# How to create list of duplicates of another list python

Tags: python

The main problem is efficiency and creating dupes of dupes.

## How to create file/list/any container with every duplicates from another list?

example inputs:
2 lists:

names = ['brian', 'adam', 'mickey', 'brian', 'mouse', 'barbara', 'mouse']

files = ['brian the wise', 'adam not interesting', 'mickey the fatty', 'brian
intelligent', 'mouse notmikey', 'barbara smartie', 'mouse clicknotclik']

I tried method:

```
    for name in names:
        for j in range(len(names)):
            if not names.index(name)==j:
                if name == names[j]:
                    number = names.index(name)
                    a = open(title + ".txt", 'a')
                    a.write('\n' + str(files[number]) + str(files[j])+'\n')
                    a.close()
```

And it worked but not really *efficient*. I got output with duplicates.

*The names and files types are lists.*

*Names* contains **one word** and *files* contains this **name and some data**.

I need to find the same names *(that's why I created another list called Names)* in Names, when it finds it, it should create a txt with whole data from list *files*.

I know it's pretty complicated but I really tried to make my target clear.

**Edit:**

Alright, the desired output is:

```
brian the wise
brian the intelligent

mouse notmikey
mouse clicknotclik
```

When the real output is:

```
brian the wise
brian intelligent

brian the wise
brian intelligent

mouse notmikey
mouse clicknotclik

mouse notmikey
mouse clicknotclik
```

I know it's because it's checking the second Brian but i want this to write it just once if it found it.

Comment: I've read this 10 times and understand nothing. That's why it's good to provide **input** and **output** in question.

Comment: inputs are 2 lists:
names = ['brian', 'adam', 'mickey', 'brian', 'mouse']
files = ['brian the wise', 'adam not interesting', 'mickey the fatty', 'brian intelligent', 'mouse notmikey']

Comment: Add this data into question.

Comment: these are example lists

Comment: the indexes of two lists matches together

Comment: it would be considerably easier if you do as @OlvinRoght told you. Make an example input (ex: Names = ['something', 'somename'], Files=[...]) and an example output.

Comment: What is `title`?

Comment: is it more clear now?

Comment: title is the least important. any string - just the name of file

Comment: Is it required that each line in output have exactly two strings?

Comment: @TomaszDąbrowski, you haven't provided desired output yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all indexes of name into a dict and write to file only "information" duplicate entries:

```
names = ["brian", "adam", "mickey", "brian", "mickey", "mouse", "brian"]
files = ["brian the wise", "adam not interesting", "mickey the fatty", "brian intelligent",
         "mickey the creepy", "mouse notmikey", "brian the mad"]
title = "omg_what_a_weird_task"

with open(title + ".txt", "a") as f:
    tmp = {}
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        if name not in tmp:
            tmp[name] = [i]
        else:
            tmp[name].append(i)
    for name, indexes in tmp.items():
        if len(indexes) > 1:
            f.write("\n".join(files[i] for i in indexes))
            f.write("\n")
```

Comment: @TomaszDąbrowski, next time try to provide examples of input and output without additional requests ;)

Comment: @Olvini Roght Sorry for that, never before submitted an issue - always good by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with comprehension lists

This will try to see for each element of `files` if it contains at least one element from `names`.

The `list(set())` clears duplicates

```py
with open(title + '.txt', 'a') as f:
    [f.write("\n{}\n".format(entry)) for entry in files for name in list(set(names)) if name in entry]
```

Without comprehension lists:

```py
with open(title + '.txt', 'a') as f:
   for name in list(set(names)):
      for entry in files:
          f.write("\n{}\n".format(entry))
```

Comment: @TomaszDąbrowski hope it's more readable, if you have any more questions let me know